# Cannot run program "adb" from IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, bash, shell, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

My problem is that I want to run shell command from Java code (my IntelliJ plugin):

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb devices")

But then I receive IOException:

> Cannot run program "adb": error=2, No such file or directory.

What is odd is that when I run it on debug mode it works, it's broken only when I deploy my plugin to real IntelliJ. The command also works from any terminal.
The only thing which works now it typing the command with full path:

> /Users/adamstyrc/utils/adb

But it's not a solution. How to fix it ? My guess would be to manually load bash PATH variable add adb exec file to project but it's not elegant solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the path, etc, are correct.

Comment: Yes, because from the terminal it works properly. The path is not recognised by IntelliJ I think but I don't know why

Comment: Okay, and I guess you ran intellij from the same terminal, so you can be sure it picked up the same paths (or if you modified the path variables you restarted the terminal & intellij)

Comment: Now I see that when I ran my IntelliJ from terminal:
> open ../IntelliJ
It actually works! But normally ppl don't run it like that. So how to load the PATH var to IntelliJ process launched like that ? Is there any Java command ?

Comment: I think you just need to start intellij from a terminal with the correct path - please see my answer, i tried to explain it as best i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure that the correct path settings are passed to IntelliJ.

If you for example modified the path settings, or if you ran intellij from a different terminal or user, then they might not be correct.

To be sure, close down IntelliJ, start a new terminal - then verify the path settings - and start IntelliJ manually from that terminal.

Comment: But I don't want to run IntelliJ from terminal. I want to launch it normally. Could adding adb exec file to project be a solution ? Any other ideas ?

Comment: Well, when it is launched "normally" there simply needs the correct path and so forth. You could verify the runtime properties in intellij via writing a simple test, i believe.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a 64 bit machine, try installing 32-bit libraries using

```
      apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Is this serious answer ? I run on mac osx btw and this is rather for linux.